# Mapreduce job give empty output on cluster

Tags: java, hadoop, intellij-idea, mapreduce

I have developed a mapreduce code which runs fine on Intellij and gives the output. When I run the same code on the cluster, I get an empty result.I keep getting the error

> 15/07/21 08:28:04 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1436660204513_0254_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
>   Error: Plink/PlinkMapper : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Also, the shuffle in final merge has failed.

```
Map-Reduce Framework
                Map input records=18858
                Map output records=0
                Map output bytes=0
```

I am using the same version of jdk during compile and run and I have no clue why I keep getting this error.Please find my code below:

**Driver:**

```
package Plink;

/**
 * Created by Sai Bharath on 7/21/2015.
 */
import Utils.PlinkConstants;
import Utils.PlinkDataSetDto;
import Utils.PlinkDto;
import Utils.PropertyUtils;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.DistributedCache;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;
/**
 * Created by bvarre on 10/29/2014.
 */
public class PlinkDriver extends Configured implements Tool {

    @Override
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {


        if (args.length < 6) {
            System.err.printf("Usage: %s [generic options] <input> <output>\n",
                    getClass().getSimpleName());
            ToolRunner.printGenericCommandUsage(System.err);
            return -1;
        }
        Job job = new Job();
        Configuration conf=job.getConfiguration();
        conf.set("mapred.child.java.opts","-Xmx8g");




        job.setJarByClass(PlinkDriver.class);


        PropertyUtils.setConfigFromSystemProperty(job.getConfiguration());

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[2]));


        if(args[3] != null && !args[3].isEmpty() && PlinkConstants.LOCAL_FILE_INPUT.equalsIgnoreCase(args[3])){
            job.getConfiguration().set("snip.codes", args[4]);
            job.getConfiguration().set("gene.codes", args[5]);
        }
        else {

            DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new Path(args[4]).toUri(), job.getConfiguration());
            DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new Path(args[5]).toUri(), job.getConfiguration());

            DistributedCache.createSymlink(conf);
        }


        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

        job.setMapperClass(PlinkMapper.class);
        // job.setCombinerClass(PlinkCombiner.class);
        job.setReducerClass(PlinkReducer.class);

        //Setup Partitioner
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(PlinkDto.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new PlinkDriver(),args);
        System.exit(exitCode);
    }
}
```

**Mapper:**

```
package Plink;

import Utils.PlinkDataSetDto;
import Utils.PlinkDto;
import Utils.PlinkResourceBundle;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class PlinkMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, PlinkDto> {


    private List<String> snipCodes = new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<String> geneCodes = new ArrayList<String>();

    private String domain;


    @Override
    protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException,
            InterruptedException {
        super.setup(context);
        Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();

        snipCodes = PlinkResourceBundle.getCodes(conf, "snip.codes");
        geneCodes = PlinkResourceBundle.getCodes(conf, "gene.codes");

        System.out.println(" snip code size in nMapper :: " + snipCodes.size());
        System.out.println(" gene code size in nMapper :: " + geneCodes.size());
    }

    @Override
    protected void map(Object key, Text value,
                       Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        try {

            String str = (value.toString());
            if (str != null && !str.equals("")) {
                List<String> items = Arrays.asList(str.split("\\s+"));
                if(items!=null && items.size()>=3) {
                    List<PlinkDto> snipList = new ArrayList<PlinkDto>();
                    List<PlinkDto> geneList = new ArrayList<PlinkDto>();
                    Text plinkKey = new Text();
                    plinkKey.set(items.get(0));
                    if(!items.get(2).equalsIgnoreCase("null") && !items.get(2).equalsIgnoreCase("na")) {
                        PlinkDto plinkDto = new PlinkDto();
                        plinkDto.setCodeDesc(items.get(1));
                        plinkDto.setCodeValue(new Float(items.get(2)));
                        if (snipCodes.contains(items.get(1))) {
                            plinkDto.setCode("SNIP");
                            snipList.add(plinkDto);
                        } else if (geneCodes.contains(items.get(1))) {
                            plinkDto.setCode("GENE");
                            geneList.add(plinkDto);
                        }
                        context.write(plinkKey,plinkDto);
                    }
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            //Collecting Patient data
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

**Reducer:**

```
package Plink;

/**
 * Created by Sai Bharath on 7/15/2015.
 */
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import Utils.PlinkDataSetDto;
import Utils.PlinkDto;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;



public class PlinkReducer extends Reducer<Text, PlinkDto, Text, Text> {


    @Override
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<PlinkDto> values, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        List<PlinkDto> snipList = new ArrayList<PlinkDto>();
        List<PlinkDto> geneList = new ArrayList<PlinkDto>();
        Iterator<PlinkDto> it=values.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            PlinkDto tempDto =  it.next();
            if (tempDto.getCode().equalsIgnoreCase("SNIP")) {
                PlinkDto snipDto = new PlinkDto();
                snipDto.setCode(tempDto.getCode());
                snipDto.setCodeDesc(tempDto.getCodeDesc());
                snipDto.setCodeValue(tempDto.getCodeValue());
                snipList.add(snipDto);
            } else if (tempDto.getCode().equalsIgnoreCase("GENE")) {
                PlinkDto geneDto = new PlinkDto();
                geneDto.setCode(tempDto.getCode());
                geneDto.setCodeDesc(tempDto.getCodeDesc());
                geneDto.setCodeValue(tempDto.getCodeValue());
                geneList.add(geneDto);
            }
        }

        for(PlinkDto snip:snipList){
            for(PlinkDto gene:geneList){
                PlinkDataSetDto dataSetDto = new PlinkDataSetDto();
                dataSetDto.setSnipCodeDesc(snip.getCodeDesc());
                dataSetDto.setGeneCodeDesc(gene.getCodeDesc());
                dataSetDto.setSnipCodeValue(snip.getCodeValue());
                dataSetDto.setGeneCodeValue(gene.getCodeValue());
                Text output = new Text();
                output.set(dataSetDto.toString());
                context.write(key,output);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**PlinkResourceBundle**

```
package Utils;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.filecache.DistributedCache;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;

import java.util.*;

public class PlinkResourceBundle {

    private PlinkResourceBundle() {
    }

    public static List<String> getCodes(Configuration conf, String codeType) throws IOException {
        List<String> codeList = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            String inFile = conf.get(codeType);

            if (inFile != null) {
                List<String> lines = HdfsUtils.readFile(inFile);
                for (String line : lines) {
                    if (line != null && line.length() > 0) {
                        codeList.add(line.trim());
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Path[] cachefiles = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(conf);
                if (cachefiles.length > 0) {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(cachefiles[0].toString()));
                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        codeList.add((line.trim()));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error in getting snip/gene codes " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        return codeList;
    }//end of method
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>Plink</groupId>
    <artifactId>Plink</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <jdkLevel>1.7</jdkLevel>
        <requiredMavenVersion>[3.3,)</requiredMavenVersion>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.build.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.outputEncoding>

    </properties>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>code-artifacts</id>
            <url>
                http://code/artifacts/content/repositories/releases
            </url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>code-artifacts</id>
            <url>
                http://code/artifacts/content/repositories/snapshots
            </url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdkLevel}</source>
                    <target>${jdkLevel}</target>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
                        <version>2.9.2-01</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                        <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
                        <version>2.4.3-01</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>

                            <includeScope>provided</includeScope>
                            <includeScope>compile</includeScope>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
            </snapshots>
            <id>HDPReleases</id>
            <name>HDP Releases</name>
            <url>http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0.2.2.4.2-2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.oozie</groupId>
            <artifactId>oozie-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.20.2</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.mrunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>mrunit</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <classifier>hadoop2</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>

15/07/22 08:41:57 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
15/07/22 08:42:06 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
15/07/22 08:42:13 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
15/07/22 08:42:13 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1436660204513_0286 completed successfully
15/07/22 08:42:13 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 50
        File System Counters
                FILE: Number of bytes read=6
                FILE: Number of bytes written=364577
                FILE: Number of read operations=0
                FILE: Number of large read operations=0
                FILE: Number of write operations=0
                HDFS: Number of bytes read=604494
                HDFS: Number of bytes written=0
                HDFS: Number of read operations=9
                HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
                HDFS: Number of write operations=2
        Job Counters
                Launched map tasks=2
                Launched reduce tasks=1
                Other local map tasks=1
                Rack-local map tasks=1
                Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=13453
                Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=9188
                Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=13453
                Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=4594
                Total vcore-seconds taken by all map tasks=13453
                Total vcore-seconds taken by all reduce tasks=4594
                Total megabyte-seconds taken by all map tasks=27551744
                Total megabyte-seconds taken by all reduce tasks=18817024
        Map-Reduce Framework
                Map input records=18858
                Map output records=0
                Map output bytes=0
                Map output materialized bytes=12
                Input split bytes=266
                Combine input records=0
                Combine output records=0
                Reduce input groups=0
                Reduce shuffle bytes=12
                Reduce input records=0
                Reduce output records=0
                Spilled Records=0
                Shuffled Maps =2
                Failed Shuffles=0
                Merged Map outputs=2
                GC time elapsed (ms)=118
                CPU time spent (ms)=10260
                Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=1023930368
                Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=9347194880
                Total committed heap usage (bytes)=5474615296
        Shuffle Errors
                BAD_ID=0
                CONNECTION=0
                IO_ERROR=0
                WRONG_LENGTH=0
                WRONG_MAP=0
                WRONG_REDUCE=0
        File Input Format Counters
                Bytes Read=604228
        File Output Format Counters
                Bytes Written=0
```

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an incompatibility with the runtime Java VM on the cluster. The "Unsupported major.minor version 51.0" indicates that the class file PlinkMapper requires at least a Java 7 VM. I would recommend confirming what version of the JRE is running on the cluster.

The major version numbers as defined in class files are listed below -

- J2SE 8 = 52
- J2SE 7 = 51
- J2SE 6.0 = 50
- J2SE 5.0 = 49
- JDK 1.4 = 48
- JDK 1.3 = 47
- JDK 1.2 = 46
- JDK 1.1 = 45

Comment: Thank you for the reply Andy. I verified that and both the JDK and JRE are the same, which is Java 7 VM.